# Creating new custom forms in SCSM 2012 using an existing form as a base

Tags: scsm-2012

I'm trying to create a custom form that is essentially the Service Request form with a few extra fields. I do not want to extend the default SR form. I will be creating a Request Offering in the Self-Service Portal that takes data like first name, last name, department, manager, etc and uses an Orchestrator runbook to create that user (among other things.)

Since these additional fields will only be used for this one automated task, I don't want to extend the normal SR form, since these fields will not be useful in a general SR.

I've created a new class and added the properties in the Authoring tool, but when I go to create the form, I get a blank form. I don't want to build it from scratch, I just want to copy the existing SR form and add some boxes that map to my new properties in the new class. Is there an easy way to do this? Am I going about this customization the wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I'm a dumbass.

You can set the imported Orchestrator runbook inputs to Text1, Text2, Text3, etc in the Runbook Automation Activity template and then map the input fields from the Self-Service Portal to Text1, Text2, etc. This will feed the data directly to the runbook while making a recording the `User Input` field of the SR, which completely negates the need for form customization.